# HttpWebRequest - ContentLength Warning

Tags: soap, header, request

I'm having the following warning, and I couldn't see any solution, maybe beacuse I'm sleepy,

Here is code to send request;

```
string requestUrl = string.Format(xml, customerNo, -2, requestXml);
        string url = WebServiceParameters.GetString("_SERVICE") + requestUrl;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "Name", "Pass"))));
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Length: 0");
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        LogRequest(requestUrl);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254"));

        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        LogResponse(result);

        sr.Close();
        response.Close();
```

Here is the error;
 The 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably because of Content-Length, but when I delete, It gives 411 error;The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required.

Answer (score 0):

try using this in your web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Now, it returns "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." but maybe because of header information, I will try, thank you!